# python: reverse a number in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, reverse

I have a string as follows,

```
s= 'Mary was born in 3102 in England.'
```

I would like to reverse the number in this string to '2013' so the output would be,

```
s_output = 'Mary was born in 2013 in England.'
```

I have done the following but do not get the result I am looking for.

```
import re
word = r'\d{4}'
s_output = s.replace(word,word[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` here with a callback function:

```py
s = 'Mary was born in 3102 in England.'
output = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: m.group()[::-1], s)
print(output)  # Mary was born in 2013 in England.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your "word" variable is a regex expression that is not evaluated yet. You need to evaluate it on your "s" string first, you can do this with re.search method, like this:

```
import re
s= 'Mary was born in 3102 in England.'
word = re.search('\d{4}',s).group(0)
s_output = s.replace(word,word[::-1]) #Mary was born in 2013 in Englan
```